# setting environment variables on amazon ec2 server for a website using stripe

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, flask, environment-variables, stripe-payments

Total noob Question I am trying to setup a stripe payment system for a website i am building using amazon ec2 using python python, flask and stripe etc . inside my `__init__.py` folder i have to set environment variables named SECRET_KEY and PUBLISHABLE_KEY so that i can run the following code.

```
stripe_keys = {
    'secret_key': os.environ['SECRET_KEY'],
    'publishable_key': os.environ['PUBLISHABLE_KEY']
}
```

stripe.api_key = stripe_keys['secret_key']

i use the export SECRET_KEY=xxxxxxxxx and export PUBLISHABLE_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxx , command under the directory of the root folder that houses my `__init__.py` file and reload apache but my app crashes, this command works when running the app locally on my pc . I also tried setting the environment variables under my wsgi file but it crashes there too. Im having a hard time finding where to set these variables using amazons documentation. is there something im missing ??...please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables should be set from the WSGI script file. This can be explicitly in the code, or the required values could be read from some external configuration file or otherwise and set based on those values.